# Change external html header active menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an external Bootstrap navbar header which I include in every page as

```
<?php include("header.html");?>
```

The external header html file is given below:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="homepage.php" >Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Members<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">4th Year</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3rd Year</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2nd Year</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1st Year</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="register"><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The problem I am facing is changing the active menu. I tried various ways but no success yet.
Please help if you have any idea.

Comment: Sorry for the problem. I updated the question.

Comment: By using Jquery you can add remove Classes

Comment: I tried that but its are not permanent. The class becomes again inactive when page opens as I have a separate header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either send a variable through POST/GET using php and set the class accordingly, or you can try using jquery to find specific elements that exist in each page and add a class accordingly, for example

```
if ($('#specific-page-element-1').length) {
  $('menuelement-1').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can open the header.html file and modify the class and save it.

Comment: I can't think of any other way to do it that the one I mentioned above, however I am certain you can't do it by using css/html.