# Is using php to include a menu for a large no. html pages a good idea?

Tags: php, html

I want certain elements like the main menu to be on every page of my website and I wanted a way to be able to make changes without having to edit every html page.

I've got a file called 'menu1.php' with the menu html code and I've used the following to include it on the page(s):

```
<php include("menu1.php"); ?>
```

This works fine when I change the extension on my pages to .php from .html.

Before I go too far I want advice as to whether this is an acceptable practice or am I heading for a fall?

Comment: I recommend you to use some PHP framework. Even if your webpage isn't large.

Comment: you can only include php code in files that get executed by your php-interpreter, which are usually only files with a .php extension.

Comment: Not only is it acceptable, it's required. It must be a `.php` page. That's why it works when you change the extension to `.php`.

Comment: Tip: To make your code look neater you can remove the brackets from the include statement.

Comment: If you plan on building your site in plain HTML with no server side dynamic content other than includes you could take a look at something like http://jekyllrb.com which would give you templates etc... without the need for server side processing every time a user looks at your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is acceptable, indeed. Honestly, this is what all novice developers do. If you have around 20 pages which have the same header menu, you should definitely follow this approach, since editing one file is way better than editing 20 files.

However, complications might occur when you need to make a menu of class `active`. Suppose you have a page called `contactus.html`. Now, when someone clicks on it, you'd need to make this tab active. However, you have a different setting in your `menu.php` file. To fix this problem, have a look at this answer :- [Change external html header active menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590975/change-external-html-header-active-menu)

Also, I'd suggest you to use a framework or templating system like `Smarty - http://www.smarty.net/` or `PlatesPHP - http://platesphp.com/`