# How to make active class for url while using external header file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created general header file that included all nav links and includes that file in each html page. While doing so I want to know if there is a way to make active page identification like background for the link and so on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change external html header active menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590975/change-external-html-header-active-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way to do this is by using php. In the external file instead of writing `class=active` using php script if($page=='home'){echo "active"} then it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you're going the vanilla route with the JS and no framework you can use `location.pathname` and match that with an `href` on `a`.

Let's say you're at `https://example.com/about`.

So, you can do:

```js
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-path', location.pathname)
```

Then with your CSS do something like:

```css
[data-path="/about"] a[href="/about"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Which would match this link on a page.

```html
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

Though, if you're using a framework of some sort this might be a lot more straight forward.